# Juniper SRX Cluster and Switching with AWS Direct Connect

Tags: juniper-srx, aws

We have a setup of two SRXs (345) in cluster mode that connect to AWS Direct Connect, each SRX connects to one AWS Connection on a local interface. The SRX also functions as a switch for two Kemp Load Balancers.

The problem is, I can only reach the Kemp Load Balancers if traffic is coming from the AWS connection that is connected to the Primary SRX.

From tracing it seems the ICMP is reaching the Kemps but the SRX is failing to find routing back to AWS.

Configuration of the cluster:

```
set security forwarding-options family mpls mode flow-based

set groups node0 system host-name node0-router
set groups node0 interfaces fxp0 disable
set groups node1 system host-name node1-router
set groups node1 interfaces fxp0 disable
set apply-groups "${node}"

set interfaces fab0 fabric-options member-interfaces ge-0/0/6
set interfaces fab1 fabric-options member-interfaces ge-5/0/6
set interfaces swfab0 fabric-options member-interfaces ge-0/0/7
set interfaces swfab1 fabric-options member-interfaces ge-5/0/7

set chassis cluster control-link-recovery

set chassis cluster redundancy-group 0 node 0 priority 100
set chassis cluster redundancy-group 0 node 1 priority 1
set chassis cluster redundancy-group 1 node 0 priority 100
set chassis cluster redundancy-group 1 node 1 priority 1
set chassis cluster redundancy-group 1 preempt
set chassis cluster reth-count 1

set interfaces irb unit 10 family inet address 172.31.0.1/24

set vlans V10-DATA vlan-id 10
set vlans V10-DATA l3-interface irb.10

set interfaces ge-0/0/0 description Kemp01:Port0
set interfaces ge-0/0/0 unit 0 family ethernet-switching interface-mode access
set interfaces ge-0/0/0 unit 0 family ethernet-switching vlan members V10-DATA
set interfaces ge-5/0/0 description Kemp02:Port0
set interfaces ge-5/0/0 unit 0 family ethernet-switching interface-mode access
set interfaces ge-5/0/0 unit 0 family ethernet-switching vlan members V10-DATA

set interfaces ge-0/0/15 description "Direct Connect to your Amazon VPC or AWS Cloud A"
set interfaces ge-0/0/15 flexible-vlan-tagging
set interfaces ge-0/0/15 mtu 1522
set interfaces ge-0/0/15 gigether-options no-auto-negotiation
set interfaces ge-0/0/15 unit 101 vlan-id 101
set interfaces ge-0/0/15 unit 101 family inet mtu 1500
set interfaces ge-0/0/15 unit 101 family inet address 169.254.255.6/30

set interfaces ge-5/0/15 description "Direct Connect to your Amazon VPC or AWS Cloud B"
set interfaces ge-5/0/15 flexible-vlan-tagging
set interfaces ge-5/0/15 mtu 1522
set interfaces ge-5/0/15 gigether-options no-auto-negotiation
set interfaces ge-5/0/15 unit 100 vlan-id 100
set interfaces ge-5/0/15 unit 100 family inet mtu 1500
set interfaces ge-5/0/15 unit 100 family inet address 169.254.255.2/30

set security zones security-zone trust host-inbound-traffic system-services all
set security zones security-zone trust interfaces irb.10
set security zones security-zone trust interfaces irb.11
set security zones security-zone trust interfaces ge-5/0/15.100
set security zones security-zone trust interfaces ge-0/0/15.101

set security policies from-zone trust to-zone trust policy permit-all match source-address any
set security policies from-zone trust to-zone trust policy permit-all match destination-address any 
set security policies from-zone trust to-zone trust policy permit-all match application any
set security policies from-zone trust to-zone trust policy permit-all then permit

set policy-options policy-statement EXPORT-PREFIXES term PREFIXES from route-filter 172.31.0.0/18 exact
set policy-options policy-statement EXPORT-PREFIXES term PREFIXES then accept
set policy-options policy-statement EXPORT-PREFIXES term REJECT then reject

set protocols bgp group EBGP type external
set protocols bgp group EBGP peer-as 64513
set protocols bgp group EBGP export EXPORT-PREFIXES
set protocols bgp group EBGP neighbor 169.254.255.1 local-address 169.254.255.2
set protocols bgp group EBGP neighbor 169.254.255.5 local-address 169.254.255.6

set routing-options autonomous-system 64514
set routing-options static route 172.31.0.0/18 discard
```

### Update

I also configured:

```
set protocols l2-learning global-mode switching
set protocols rstp bridge-priority 4k
set protocols rstp interface all
```

the output of `show chassis cluster control-plane statistics`:

```
Control link statistics:
    Control link 0:
        Heartbeat packets sent: 1634
        Heartbeat packets received: 1506
        Heartbeat packet errors: 0
Fabric link statistics:
    Child link 0
        Probes sent: 659
        Probes received: 659
    Child link 1
        Probes sent: 0
        Probes received: 0
```

The output of `show chassis cluster ethernet-switching interfaces` is:

```
swfab0:

    Name               Status      
    ge-0/0/7           up         
swfab1:

    Name               Status      
    ge-5/0/7           up
```

Output of `show route terse`:

```
inet.0: 7 destinations, 7 routes (7 active, 0 holddown, 0 hidden)
+ = Active Route, - = Last Active, * = Both

A V Destination        P Prf   Metric 1   Metric 2  Next hop        AS path
* ? 169.254.255.0/30   D   0                       >ge-5/0/15.100
* ? 169.254.255.2/32   L   0                        Local
* ? 172.18.0.0/16      B 170        100                             64513 I
  unverified                                       >169.254.255.1
* ? 172.19.0.0/16      B 170        100                             64513 I
  unverified                                       >169.254.255.1
* ? 172.31.0.0/18      S   5                        Discard
* ? 172.31.0.0/24      D   0                       >irb.10      
* ? 172.31.0.1/32      L   0                        Local

inet6.0: 1 destinations, 1 routes (1 active, 0 holddown, 0 hidden)
+ = Active Route, - = Last Active, * = Both

A V Destination        P Prf   Metric 1   Metric 2  Next hop        AS path
* ? ff02::2/128        I   0                        MultiRecv
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your config looks good - can you confirm that your swfab interfaces are connected to each other?  Eg: 0/0/7 on node 0 is patched to 5/0/7 on node 1?

```
show chassis cluster ethernet-switching interfaces
```

Should show Up/Up on both ports

Comment: I wonder if I need to configure OSPF on the irb.10 interface?

Comment: I'm not seeing the directly attached route for ge-0/0/15 - 169.254.255.6/30 - can you confirm this interface is up?

Comment: I've tested if everything works when that port is down. This is why it was down in the logs.

Comment: I actually started from scratch, now without `set protocols l2-learning global-mode switching`, not sure if related and now everything works.

Comment: Good catch - yes, you need to have global-mode switching configured, or the SRX won't forward over the swfab link, partitioning your VLAN, which describes your symptoms exactly.